# If $x<y$ then $\exists\, M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<y-x\;\forall\; n>M$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I am wondering how I would

Prove  for every pair of positive integers $x$ $y$ where such  $x<y$ there exist a natural number $M$ such that if $n$ is a natural number and $n>M$ then $\frac{1}{n}<(y-x)$

So I did $y>x$ so then $y-x>0$

let $M=\frac{1}{y-x}+1$ and I guess you could use floor function on the $\frac{1}{y-x}$

So then if $n>M>\frac{1}{y-x}$ then $1/n<\frac{1}{y-x}$

not sure if this proof is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path. Just choose $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M>\frac{1}{y-x}$ (existence is guaranteed by [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Ordered_fields)).

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the set of integers $n$ such that
$$n>\frac{1}{y-x}$$
Then $S$ is non-empty and bounded below, and you can take $M$ to be the least element of $S$.